# Load TinyMCE on dynamic loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, tinymce-4

In my page I'm loading different textareas based on the button pressed. Suppose a user clicks on button A, then this script is called:

```
$("body").on("click", "a#pages-menu", function() {
    var page = $(this).attr("id");
    $(".inject").load("Including/modules/"+page+"/index.php", function () {
    });
});
```

On this module, there is a `<textarea></textarea>` on which I want to initialize a TinyMCE. I tried using some of the code provided by TinyMCE documentation, but that didn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setup() {
        tinyMCE.init({
            mode : "textareas",
            theme : "advanced",
            plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
            theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
            theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing : true
        });
    }
</script>
```

and then `setup()` after `load()`, but as I said before, that didn't work.

Comment: Could you create a `jsFiddle` replicating the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NDH83/

Comment: @MelanciaUK That's the basic system, what I don't know is how I can add the TinyMCE to that `<textarea>`, I couldn't even get it imported in the jsfiddle...